# Authorization code flow: where is User identity information?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

A typical request to get authorization code is:

```
https://authorization-server.com/auth?response_type=code&client_id=2935291598237423985&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample-app.com%2Fcallback&scope=create+delete&state=xcoiv98y2kd22vusuye3kch
```

There is no user identity information in this request. How do the authorization server (e.g. Google) know which user's permission is needed to issue the authorization code to the application (e.g. stack overflow)?

Comment: 'user identity information' - this is unclear. Are you asking where the user credentials are sent or how Google knows if you need access to e.g. the user's Google Drive? Can you explain a bit more about what you're attempting here?

Comment: For example, when I'm trying to access stack overflow, I choose login through Google. Then I will get redirected to Google authorization server, this redirection URL should include my identity saved on Google so that Google can specifically ask for MY permission.

Comment: No the redirection doesn't include your identity as otherwise, everyone would be redirecting to login with techie11's credentials. Once you've subsequently logged in successfully with Google, Google then provides the relevant information. Until you login, Stack Overflow knows nothing about you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial request/redirect does not contain user identity information.

The code flow is based on redirects. The authorization server will ask the end user to login (or automatically log in the end user). The authorization server and the end user will exchange several requests to authenticate the end user.

The user that logs in to the authorization Server is the subject the relying party will receive.

See the [OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) for more information on the code flow.